# Fiddler Auto Responder + Regular Expression

Tags: regex, fiddler

I know that the title is not very descriptive but here's what I just cant figure out!!
Okay so I have something like the following URL:

```
http://realsite.com/Stuff/start.ashx?blah=blah1&RandomStuffHere&blah=false
```

So I need to either redirect it or supply it with my site:

```
http://My_Site.com/Stuff/newstart.ashx?blah=blah1&RandomStuffHere&blah=true
```

Realize how I kept everything the same except for the domain which I changed to mine, and the bool value at the end.
I have searched, and searched and still cant find anything that works.

I currently am trying a REGEX solution but it wont let me change the bool at end.
`REGEX:.*/Stuff/start.ashx(.*)`

So if anyone can provide something like this that lets me redirect to my site with everything the same as the New url except for changing the bool at end, I will be forever in your debt! :D

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 13):

Fiddler Auto Responder might not be the right thing for you, the position of the query string parameters and other strings in the URL is important for a regex.

## Alternative

Consider using [FiddlerScript](http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp) where you can redirect traffic to your domain like this:

Inside `OnBeforeRequest`

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("realsite.com") && oSession.uriContains("Stuff/start.ashx")) {
    oSession.hostname = "My_Site.com";
    oSession.url = oSession.url.Replace("Stuff/start.ashx", "newstuff/start.ashx");
    oSession.url = oSession.url.Replace("&blah=false", "&blah=true");
}
```

Although this example is not 100% accurate this should get you going in the right direction.
This gives you more control over manipulating complex URLs, which your URL's look like they could get complex.

## Auto Responder

The regex would look something like this, capturing the "random" parts of the URL, assumes `blah=false` is always at the end:

```
regex:(?insx)^http://realsite.com/Stuff/start.ashx?(.*)&blah=false$ #Match the query string always with blah=false at end
```

And the replacement:

```
http://My_Site.com/Stuff/newstart.ashx?$1&blah=true
```

Here is a screen grab for completeness:
[image: Screen grab of regex in place in Fiddler]

Comment: But thats the thing I wanted to use Fiddlerscript but someone told me to use Auto Responder xd Plus the URL that I want to redirect FROM always changes like a certain peice of data, so I have to have some form of wildcard which is why I chose AutoResponder for the REGEX part :/.... If FS can still do this, maybe could u give me a more complete example :D

Comment: Actually.... your post may be of use.... even tho it doesnt solve the whole thing I could still use the Replace part and change false to true  [EDIT] Actually, again ;3, You may have just solved it :D :D: :D :D

Comment: Tried it and it Replaced the hostname, I think your solution works :)

Comment: Fiddler's AutoResponder can absolutely transform any URL into any other URL (it supports regular-expression group replacements). Having said that, many people find Regular Expressions hard to use, and the FiddlerScript method you suggest works fine too.

Comment: @EricLaw thanks for your comments, I have clarified the answer - making clear my thoughts at the time.

Comment: That n option actually breaks your example by disabling explicit capture, just to save anyone else who finds this the trouble: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: :D Thank you so much, you just saved me a bunch of trouble